# HamburgerMenuItem IsEnabled property cannot be updated on runtime

Tags: wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

I am having a problem updating the IsEnabled property from HamburgerMenuItem.
First, I set the value of IsEnabledProperty to be false, and then during runtime, I am trying to change it to true, but debugger keeps saying that the value is false. And, of course the UI also still shows that it is disabled. Below is the code:

View:

```
xmlns:controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"

<UserControl.Resources>
   <DataTemplate x:Key="MenuItemTemplate" DataType="{x:Type metro:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem}">
        <Grid Height="50">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column=0 Text="{Binding Glyph}"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column=1 Text="{Binding Label}"/>
        </Grid>
   </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
<controls:x:Name="HamburgerMenuControl"
          DisplayMode="CompactInline"
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MenuItemTemplate}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems, Mode=OneWay}"/>
<Button Content="Test Button" Command="{Binding TestCommand, Mode=OneTime}"/>
```

ViewModel:

```
private HamburgerMenuItemCollection menuItems;
public HamburgerMenuItemCollection MenuItems
{
    get {return menuItems;}
    set {SetProperty(ref menuItems, value);}
}
public ICommand TestCommand {get; private set;}

public MyVM()
{
   MenuItems = new HamburgerMenuItemCollection()
   {
       new HamburgerMenuGlyphItem()
       {
          Glyph="1",
          Label="1"
       };
       // Second MenuItem is disabled
       new HamburgerMenuGlyphItem()
       {
          Glyph="2",
          Label="2",
          IsEnabled=false;
       };
   };
   TestCommand = new DelegateCommand(UpdateIsEnabled);
}

private void UpdateIsEnabled()
{
    var menuItem = MenuItems[1];
    menuItem.IsEnabled = true; // after this is executed, Debugger shows that IsEnabled is still false;
    if (menuItem.IsEnabled != isEnabled)
    {
       vm.BeginInvoke(() =>
       {
          vm.IsEnabled = isEnabled; // redo, but it seems like none of these are called
          vm.SetValue(HamburgerMenuGlyphItem.IsEnabledProperty, isEnabled);
          vm.SetCurrentValue(HamburgerMenuGlyphItem.IsEnabledProperty, isEnabled);
          vm.InvalidateProperty(HamburgerMenuGlyphItem.IsEnabledProperty);
       }, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal);
    }
    RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(MenuItems));
}
```

Can you show me what I did wrong and how to update the IsEnabled Dependency Property properly?

Answer (score 0):

To enable the `HamburgerMenuItem` you should sets its `Command` property to a command whose `CanExecute` method returns `true`.

You cannot just set the `IsEnabled` property to `true`. If you take a look at [how the HamburgerMenuItem class is implemented on GitHub](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/19fa2b71a2be6661ce0b8b60891fbde53633b0e1/src/MahApps.Metro/Controls/HamburgerMenu/MenuItems/HamburgerMenuItem.cs), you'll see that there is a `CoerceValueCallback` that returns the value of the private `CanExecute` method:

```
private static object IsEnabledCoerceValueCallback(DependencyObject d, object value)
{
    if (!(bool)value)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return ((HamburgerMenuItem)d).CanExecute;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like IsEnabledProperty is really useless, because it cannot be changed once value is set. (Or maybe because I am not binding it to some property). In the meantime, I will use the ICommand's CanExecute as you suggested then.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you bind it to some property. You need to use the Command property to enable/disable the item.